# Render PortletURL does not point to jsp file

Tags: java, jsp, liferay

I have the portlet with a form to add some fields and a link to the jsp showing the data table. This is file `view.jsp`:

```
<% 
  PortletURL showBooksURL = renderResponse.createRenderURL();
  showBooksURL.setParameter("showBook", "/html/addbook/showBook.jsp");
%> 

<aui form>

Click <a href = "<%=showBooksURL.toString()%>">here</a> to see the table.
```

When I click `here` the url in the browser point to `showBook.jsp` but the table doesn't show up, stay still with `view.jsp`.
What Im doing wrong??

Comment: Hi, How your render method is defined ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your parameter name should be jspPage(deprecated) or mvcPath as shown below.

`showBooksURL.setParameter("jspPage", "/html/addbook/showBook.jsp");`
or
  `showBooksURL.setParameter("mvcPath", "/html/addbook/showBook.jsp");`

You can verify code here, [MVCPortlet.java](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/blob/master/portal-service/src/com/liferay/portal/kernel/portlet/bridges/mvc/MVCPortlet.java#L452)

NOTE: Edited answer as per comment by @Olaf.

Comment: It works now, thanks, but I think the first parameter is just the name, we can name whatever we want??

Comment: Yes, thank you, now I get it. I just read in Liferay in action: "to determine what JSP to display, all you need to do is point a render parameter called jspPage to the location of the JSP"

Comment: `jspPage` is actually deprecated for a while now and you should use `mvcPath` instead. but the functionality is the same.